# split rows in excel by comma separation

Tags: vba, excel, split

I need to write some small code in excel that splits rows for data separated by comma.
Example:

```
row 1: column A: "data_1,data_2,data_3" column B:  "do_this_1"
row 2: column A: "data_4,data_5,data6" column B: "do_this_2"
```

This need to change to separate row so it will become:

```
row 1: column a: "data_1" column B: "do_this_1"
row 2: column a: "data_2" column B: "do_this_1"
row 3: column a: "data_3" column B: "do_this_1"
row 4: column a: "data_4" column B: "do_this_2"
row 5: column a: "data_5" column B: "do_this_2"
row 6: column a: "data_6" column B: "do_this_2"
```

EDIT: screenshot for more detailed questioning:
[image: screenshot]

Anyone knows how to do this with VBA code?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What have you tried so far? If nothing google is your friend. Here is the first result from google which gives you your answer.

[Linky](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193593.aspx)

Comment: I tried googling. problem with textToColumns is... wel it's to columns and not to rows ;)

Comment: Try recording this as a macro. It will do the VBA for you. - i.e. press the record, then invoke the Text to Columns functionality in the Data:Data Tool ribbon...

Comment: @BennyNiemeijer Use the textToColumns function then transpose the results. Simple ;) Otherwise you're going to be looking at using a `Do` loop

Comment: @Benny, you beat me by 5 seconds...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this:

```
Sub test_split()
    Dim Dic As Object: Set Dic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Dic.CompareMode = vbTextCompare
    Dim i&, cl As Range, data As Range, splItem, key
    Set data = Range([B1], Cells(Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row, "B")) 'replace `B` by `Q`
    For Each cl In data
        If Not Dic.exists(cl.Value2) Then
            Dic.Add cl.Value2, cl.Offset(, -1).Value2 'replace `-1` by `-16`
        Else
            Dic(cl.Value2) = Dic(cl.Value2) & "," & cl.Offset(, -1).Value2 'replace `-1` by `-16`
        End If
    Next
    Workbooks.Add: i = 1
    For Each key In Dic
        For Each splItem In Split(Dic(key), ",")
            Cells(i, "A").Value2 = key: Cells(i, "B").Value2 = splItem
            i = i + 1
        Next splItem
    Next key
End Sub
```

*Source:*

[image]

*Output:*

[image]

---

***1 update against additional requirements***

if you need combine the data back then you can use this:

```
Sub test_combine()
    Dim Dic As Object: Set Dic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Dic.CompareMode = vbTextCompare
    Dim i&, cl As Range, data As Range, key
    Set data = Range([A1], Cells(Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row, "A"))
    For Each cl In data
        If Not Dic.exists(cl.Value2) Then
            Dic.Add cl.Value2, cl.Offset(, 1).Value2
        Else
            Dic(cl.Value2) = Dic(cl.Value2) & "," & cl.Offset(, 1).Value2
        End If
    Next
    Workbooks.Add: i = 1
    For Each key In Dic
        Cells(i, "A").Value2 = key: Cells(i, "B").Value2 = Dic(key)
        i = i + 1
    Next key
End Sub
```

*Source:*

[image]

*Output:*

[image]

---

***2 update against last provided information:***

If you have more than one cell which shall be used as key then you can use this:

```
Sub test_split2()
    Dim Dic As Object: Set Dic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Dic.CompareMode = vbTextCompare
    Dim i&, cl As Range, data As Range, splItem, key, s$
    Set data = Range([A1], Cells(Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row, "A"))
    For Each cl In data
    '~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    'add in `Array()` another cells if required
        s = Join(Array(cl.Offset(, 1).Value2, _
                       cl.Offset(, 2).Value2, _
                       cl.Offset(, 3).Value2, _
                       cl.Offset(, 4).Value2), "|")

    'Currently `s` contains values from columns `B,C,D,E` - 4 values
    '~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        If Not Dic.exists(s) Then
            Dic.Add s, cl.Value2
        Else
            Dic(s) = Dic(s) & "," & cl.Value2
        End If
    Next
    Workbooks.Add: i = 1
    For Each key In Dic
        For Each splItem In Split(Dic(key), ",")
            Cells(i, "A").Value2 = splItem
            '~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
            'Change `E` to another column, depending on count of items in `Array()`
            'currently `Array()` contains 4 values from columns `B,C,D,E`
            Range(Cells(i, "B"), Cells(i, "E")) = Split(key, "|")
            '~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
            i = i + 1
        Next splItem
    Next key
End Sub
```

*Source:*

[image]

*Output:*

[image]

To combine the data back you can use this:

```
Sub test_combine2()
    Dim Dic As Object: Set Dic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Dic.CompareMode = vbTextCompare
    Dim i&, cl As Range, data As Range, splItem, key, s$
    Set data = Range([A1], Cells(Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row, "A"))
    For Each cl In data
    '~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    'add in `Array()` another cells if required
        s = Join(Array(cl.Offset(, 1).Value2, _
                       cl.Offset(, 2).Value2, _
                       cl.Offset(, 3).Value2, _
                       cl.Offset(, 4).Value2), "|")
    'Currently `s` contains values from columns `B,C,D,E` - 4 values
    '~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        If Not Dic.exists(s) Then
            Dic.Add s, cl.Value2
        Else
            Dic(s) = Dic(s) & "," & cl.Value2
        End If
    Next
    Workbooks.Add: i = 1
    For Each key In Dic
            Cells(i, "A").Value2 = Dic(key)
            '~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
            'Change `E` to another column, depending on count of items in `Array()`
            'currently in array 4 values from columns `B,C,D,E`
            Range(Cells(i, "B"), Cells(i, "E")) = Split(key, "|")
            '~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
            i = i + 1
    Next key
End Sub
```

*Source:*

[image]

*Output:*

[image]

Comment: You, Sir, are the real MVP! Thanks alot! Two questions stil, Instead of columns A&B I have A-Q for my real sheet. Can I still use this code? And second: How can I swap them back again?

Comment: @BennyNiemeijer yes, you can use this code, I've marked rows with code where you need to do replacements to apply it for your real data, and also I've posted the code to combine the data back, see updated post

Comment: Works almost, If I change B to Q and -1 to -16 it only copies column Q, but I want to copy column B - Q..How to do that? Thanks a lot for your help so far!

Comment: @BennyNiemeijer you've specified  in your initial comment that instead of A&B you need A-Q (your real data), but your last comment show that you need B-Q, so that is why instead of -16 you need -15. Another words, `offset(,-15)` will give you position of the cell which is before 15th cells of position of the cell in column `Q`

Comment: Sorry I think we don't quite understand eachother, I've editted my question with a screenshot for what I actually need. Thanks a lot again!

Comment: @BennyNiemeijer, ok, got it, see my updated post (section `2 update against last provided information:`)

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 1):

Here you go. This is an example. Try modifying it for your needs

```
Sub Example()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim addr As String

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    With ws
        addr = ActiveCell.Address

        .Range(addr).Value = "1;2;3;4;5;6"

        .Range(addr).TextToColumns Destination:=.Cells(1, 3), semicolon:=True

        .Range(.Range(addr).Offset(0, 1), .Cells(1, .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column)).Copy

        .Cells(2, 2).PasteSpecial Transpose:=True

        ' Uncomment this to clear original cell and transposed results
        ' .Range(.Range(addr), .Cells(.Range(addr).Row, .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column)).ClearContents

         .Range(addr).Select
    End With

End Sub
```

This isn't finished for what you want exactly but will give you a starting point of one way and probably the simplest to approach this.

Try using this in a blank sheet as it will create it's own example